# Drawing at floating point position

Tags: rendering, c, sdl2

The library I am using (SDL2) only supports drawing to `int` positions. I am currently storing my objects positions as `double`, and would like to render them. Should I round the value to int, i.e. `0.5 => 1`, or simply cast it to `int`, i.e. `0.5 => 0`?

Comment: As long as your rendered positions aren't negative, then rounding is the same as casting/truncating after adding 0.5 - so you'd get the same rendered result with either method as if your camera/viewpoint were nudged by half a pixel while using the other method. Does that distinction matter?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this answer will not suit your question, but I assume that you want to have float movement precision even when SDL rectangles support only integer values.

One of the tricks you can do is to have a float/double variables to track some kind of "virtual" position in your world. In your case it means having a struct **SDL_Rect** and some **float vector**. For example:

```
//Custom made generic type
Vector2<float> _position;

//SDL struct
SDL_Rect _rect;

void Object::init(float x, float y,SDL_texture* text)
{
    _position.x = x;
    _position.y = y;

    _rect.x = (int)x;
    _rect.y = (int)y;

    _texture = text;
}
```

And then the update function would look like this:

```
void Object::update(float deltaTime){

    _position.x += 5.0f * deltaTime;
    _position.y += 5.0f * deltaTime;

    _rect.x = (int)_position.x;
    _rect.y = (int)_position.y; 
}
```

That way you don't lose the movement precisions the floats have. Then you can use this position vector also for collision checks, where instead of checking SDL_Rects (in case of Rectangular collision) you check their position vectors+dimensions.

Answer (score 4):

There's a simple way to render a rectangle with floating point coordinates but for some reason it's documentation is not available on the wiki. [A commit](http://lists.libsdl.org/pipermail/commits-libsdl.org/2018-October/003226.html) was done to add this feature on October 22, 2018. [Atleast SDL 2.0.10 required.](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/c3a32605f8ad15c140005990826e404d673addd3/WhatsNew.txt#L74)

```c
SDL_FRect box = {11.5, 1.2, 10.5, 11.252};
SDL_RenderFillRectF(renderer, &box);
```

<sup>*A simple demonstration of how it can be used for rendering.*</sup>

Comment: SDL_FRect and other float versions of RenderCopy sounds to not be part of SDL2 (current 2.0.12). Any idea why?

Comment: Actually IDK, this wasn't even documented in wiki. I digged it up from header declarations and searched for a relevant reference.

Comment: https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/c3a32605f8ad15c140005990826e404d673addd3/WhatsNew.txt#L74

Answer (score 1):

SDL2 has full range of function equivalents for `float` types here back in 2023 and if you want smooth movement like `position.x += (x*delta)/speed` this functions are here to help:

Basically what I have used so far is:

`SDL_FRect` - Rectangle struct

`SDL_RenderCopyExF` - For advanced rendering

`SDL_RenderCopyF` - For simple rendering

This is additional functions I also use:

`SDL_RenderDrawRectF` - For drawing rectangle

`SDL_RenderFillRectF` - For filling rectangle

And I believe it is a deception but it feels like float type functions work faster (In fact they might be converting floats to integers I have never looked into a function sources)